# How to setup NHibernate Mapping Generator for SQLite

Tags: .net, nhibernate

How should connection be set for the Generator, if SQLite is used? I see that OLE DB provider should be choosed, but which? And is there anything else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using FluentNHibernate it would look something like this

```
using FluentNHiberante.Config.Db;

var config = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SqLiteDatabaseConfiguration.Standard.File(filepath))
    .Mapppings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemlbyOf<SomeEntityMap>())
    .BuildConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate Mapping Generator with SQLite

https://nmgs.codeplex.com/